# Why can the callable returned from std::mem_fn be used on objects and on shared_ptrs?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The following code [works](http://ideone.com/3G0MVf), but I do not understand why it does.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct foo
{
    int get_val() const
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo obj;
    std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr = std::make_shared<foo>();

    const auto getter = std::mem_fn( &foo::get_val );

    std::cout << getter( obj ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getter( ptr ) << std::endl;
}
```

Why can `getter` be used on `obj` and on `ptr`? I expected it to only work on `obj`.

Comment: "otherwise, if t1 does not satisfy the previous items, then INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) is equivalent to ((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN). "

Comment: All that is needed is some handle on (an appropriately qualified) object to call the member function for. So the standard conveniently and sensibly added all the required overloads for `std::mem_fn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`std::mem_fn` cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

> Function template `std::mem_fn` generates wrapper objects for pointers to members, which can store, copy, and invoke a pointer to member. **Both references and pointers (including smart pointers) to an object can be used when invoking a `std::mem_fn`**.

Short answer: because the standard says so.

I guess that it just a more convenient and general interface, as you can, for example, write a single *template function* that calls a `std::mem_fn` which will work with both references and pointers:

```
const auto getter = std::mem_fn( &foo::get_val );

template <typename T>
void call_getter(T&& x)
{
    // do something
    getter(x);
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    foo obj;
    std::shared_ptr<foo> ptr = std::make_shared<foo>();

    call_getter( obj );
    call_getter( ptr );
}
```

In the above example you only need one overload of `call_getter`.

Answer (score 3):

`mem_fn` is defined in terms of the callable concept, like many other things in the standard (`function`, `async`, `reference_wrapper`, etc)

The callable concept is defined in terms of `INVOKE` in the standard.

`INVOKE` reduces to, in this case:

> otherwise, if t1 does not satisfy the previous items, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)`.

(quote source: cppreference.com), where `f` is what you pass `mem_fn`. And `t1...tn` are the args you pass the return value of `mem_fn`.

And `((*smart_ptr).*mem_fun)(args...)` works.  So it works.

Less directly, because the people who wrote the standard meant it to work.

Answer (score 2):

From [this `std::mem_fn` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn):

> Both references and pointers (including smart pointers) to an object can be used when invoking a `std::mem_fn`

It simply means that the object `std::mem_fn` have overloads of the function-call operator that takes both instances and pointers (normal and smart) to instances of the object to call the function on.